Streamlit and Playwright NotImplementedError: weighing ProactorEventLoop() and 3rd-party streamlit_async
I have noted the question Why Aren't Streamlit and Playwright Playing Nicely Together (Solving NotImplementedError)? and Anderson Viana's insightful answer.
For a project hosted on Streamlit Community Cloud and GitHub, what will be the best approach to adopt?

use ProactorEventLoop()
plain asyncio.run()
use third-party Streamlit libraries to handle async, if any.

[info]
Sort of looking at: Streamlit app calls a method ext_init() in another file webtee having webtor class, which in turn calls another class PlaywrightController: in yet another file to initialize and launch a Playwright browser and context that ext_init() uses to handle its multiple logics. The PlaywrightController is meant to be a singleton and handles the async with async_playwright() as playwright:
